# Return a specific cell in a Google Sheets QUERY function

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, offset, google-query-language

Take the following spreadsheet:

[image]

I want to create a query that returns the values in columns A and B where A matches 'f' and also return the value that is in cell D1 (Test Cell).

Here is the Query that I wrote:

=QUERY(A2:B7,"select A,B,'"&D1&"' where A='f'")

This is what I expected:

[image]

This is what actually happens:

[image]

I'm not sure where the value of "Test Cell()" in C11 is coming from and I suspect it's a bug. Is there a way to accomplish what I am attempting?

Comment: what you are doing here, is you created a column with plain text from cell D1, QUERY will add LABEL to any created column by it self as header, if you don't want it, add this to your query ```label '"&D1&"' ''```, this will tell the query to replace the header of that newly created column with ```''``` (nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:B7, "select A,B,'"&D1&"' where A='f' label '"&D1&"'''")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B7, "select A,B,'"&D1&"' where A='f'", ), "offset 1", )
```